# Jumble sover or Puzzle solver load time increase

Tags: php

This is the jumble solver or puzzle solver:

[www.englishact.com/jumblesolver](http://www.englishact.com/jumblesolver)

PHP code for this solver:

```
<?php

function onereplace($str,$replaced_character){
$spt = str_split($str,1);
for($i=0; $i <= (count($spt) - 1) ; $i++){
 if($spt[$i] == $replaced_character){
   unset($spt[$i]);
   break;
 }
}

return implode('',$spt);
}



if(isset($_GET['zig'])){

$file = file("../01912424773.txt");
$post = $_GET['zig'] ;
 $length = strlen($post);

 $output[] = '<hr><h3 style="color:#e85151;" id="resulty">Result/Results</h3></hr>' ;

 foreach($file as $value){

  $value = trim($value);
  $value_proxy = strtoupper(trim($value));



  if(strlen(trim($value)) == $length){
     for($i=0;$i<=($length - 1); $i++){
      $data = strtoupper($post[$i]);
      $value_proxy = onereplace($value_proxy,$data);

    }
  //echo "value=".$value_proxy."<br>";  

    if(trim($value_proxy) == ''){
    $output[] = '<p>'.$value."</p>" ;
    }

  } // end if


  set_time_limit(0);

 } // end foreach


 foreach($output as $result){
  echo $result; 
 }

}


?>
```

Code where is taking long response time:
In loop section. Please help me to simplify the loop.

My problem:

If I host this site in 000webhost or free host then they ban my site for long response time. How to make my script as simple as possible? Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
 <?php

    function onereplace($str,$replaced_character){
    $spt = str_split($str,1);
    for($i=0; $i <= (count($spt) - 1) ; $i++){
     if($spt[$i] == $replaced_character){
       unset($spt[$i]);
       break;
     }
    }

    return implode('',$spt);
    }



    if(isset($_GET['zig'])){
    $filee = "../01912424773".strlen($_GET['zig']).".txt";

    if(file_exists($filee) ){ 


    $file = file($filee);

    }


    if(!file_exists($filee) ){ 


    $file = file("../019124247735.txt");

    }
    $post = $_GET['zig'] ;
     $length = strlen($post);

     $output[] = '<hr><h3 style="color:#e85151;" id="resulty">Result/Results</h3></hr>' ;

     foreach($file as $value){

      $value = trim($value);
      $value_proxy = strtoupper(trim($value));



      if(strlen(trim($value)) == $length){
         for($i=0;$i<=($length - 1); $i++){
          $data = strtoupper($post[$i]);
          $value_proxy = onereplace($value_proxy,$data);

        }
      //echo "value=".$value_proxy."<br>";  

        if(trim($value_proxy) == ''){
        $output[] = '<p>'.$value."</p><br>" ;
        }

      } // end if


      //set_time_limit(0);

     } // end foreach


     foreach($output as $result){
      echo $result; 

     }}

    ?>
```

Above code has solved my problem.

Comment: Commenting `set_time_limit()` is hardly an improvement of an `n³` algorithm.